# can't access webView from UiViewController subViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My UIWebView is inside my view controller, added as a SubView. I'm trying to access it from a selector's method which get the UIViewController as param, so I'm doing an array of subviews, iterating it and using `isKindOfClass:UIWebView` to find my UIWebView and execute my selector, but I can't find the webView in the array of subViews and I've got no idea of what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I do:

static UIWebView* static_iVar = nil;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
    [self configureStatic_iVarwithUrlLink:url];
}


-(void)configureStatic_iVarwithUrlLink:(NSURL *)url{

//Configure father class webView...

static_iVar = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width,height)];
//code...


[self.view addSubview:static_iVar];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.view subviews]);

}
```

This Nslog prints me this so the WebView is inside of my main view as a subview:

```
2015-08-18 16:29:50.719 Hnos Lopez[1785:202794] (
    "<_UILayoutGuide: 0x14564180; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x14564330>>",
    "<_UILayoutGuide: 0x14564670; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x14562520>>",
    "<UIWebView: 0x1456e530; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1456e700>>"
```

This is what happens when I press the back or refresh button, and the selector method is called:

```
-(void)goBack{
    NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.view subviews]);
    for (UIView *subview in subviews){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]] && [subview respondsToSelector:@selector(goBack)])
        {
            [subview performSelector:@selector(goBack)];
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what NSLog prints:

```
2015-08-18 16:31:44.675 Hnos Lopez[1785:202794] (
    "<UIView: 0x14562af0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x145623b0>>",
    "<ADBannerView: 0x1453cd00; frame = (0 44; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1457f620>>",
    "<UIActivityIndicatorView: 0x14591910; frame = (150 274; 20 20); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x14591b30>>",
    "<ADBannerView: 0x146af670; frame = (0 568; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x146af880>>"
```

There is no UIWebView in my subviews

Comment: Add a log of `self` to `configureStatus_iVar` (terrible name BTW) and `goBack` to make sure you are dealing with the same view controller in both places.

Comment: Side note - why would you use a static ivar for the `UIWebView` in the `configureStatic_iVar` method? Why not use a simple local variable?

Comment: Web view is _static_iVar in the first tab because I need to load the push notifications links there, and I access it from a class method thats why is a static_ivar. I got the same method with a local variable for load the webView of my children view controllers

Comment: I've editted the code below. Changed the method configureStatic_iVar:(UIViewController*)vista withUrlLink:(NSURL *)url to configureStatic_iVarwithUrlLink:(NSURL *)url And tested and it's exactly the same. My WebView is still not appearing as subView of self.

Comment: Did you see my first comment above? Add the two log statements.

Comment: It prints exactly the same. I'm accessing the same viewController in both methods: 
2015-08-18 18:56:29.978 Hnos Lopez[1899:221035] <FirstViewController: 0x156a01a0>

2015-08-18 18:56:49.559 Hnos Lopez[1899:221035] <FirstViewController: 0x156a01a0>